# Periodically Refresh a Database in Laravel for Dev/Staging Server

Tags: laravel, laravel-forge

I have a system built in Laravel 8, hosted by DigitalOcean and deployed using GitLab and Forge. I have three branches, dev/staging/master that are linked to various domains, separately controlled by Forge.

For the dev site, I want to reset the database regularly to the raw seed value. I could just run a CRON job on the server of course, but is there a best practise way of doing this, or some inbuilt Laravel functionality, that I can or should use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cron is still well suited for this job. Nothing wrong it. You could put it in [Laravel's schedule](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling) if you wish, which is still run by cron :)